# analyzing performance of javascript on mobile

Tags: javascript, performance, listview, mobile, analysis

Is there any possibility of analyzing performance of javascript on mobile. Like I have a situation where say a list is rendered quite slowly on mobile (like 3-4 minutes).

Initially i thought its because of the data model and kind of query i am using is causing the delay, but when i took database traces all the query execution is really fast.

I also got hold of n/w trace of attached device (which is simulator in my case) and could see all the data being buffered in under 3 secs. So the only culprit what i anticipate is the JS running behind to render all the data. But i dont know how to trace or do performance analysis of JS on mobile. Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, (your question somewhat confuses me) but here's how to test how long a piece of code takes in JavaScript:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(); //milliseconds

// your section of code
// ...

var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
```

You could do that to test specific sections of your code for execution length.

If you had `<div id="timetaken"></div>` somewhere in your HTML, you could add

```
document.getElementById('timetaken').innerHTML="Time taken:  " + elapsed;
```

And then when your code completes it would display how long that bit of code took to complete in your HTML so that you can see it on a mobile device.